# Can't run crontab without excecuting the programm once

Tags: python, tkinter, cron, raspberry-pi3

I wrote a `script.py` which should open a `Tkinter` window on a raspberry:

```
from Tkinter import *
import turtle
import math
import time
import sys
import os

root = Tk()
root.config(cursor="none")
ccanvas = Canvas(root, width = 800, height = 480)
root.overrideredirect(1) 
turtle_screen = turtle.TurtleScreen(ccanvas)
ccanvas.pack()
turtle = turtle.RawTurtle(turtle_screen)
turtle.hideturtle()
mainloop()
```

I am able to run the script from the command line with:

```
python /home/pi/script.py
```

When I tried to run it via `crontab` first the Display was not found. I fixed that with:

```
DISPLAY=:0 python /home/pi/script.py
```

But now I get the following error: `_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":0"` until I execute the `script.py` once manual in the cmd. Then the `crontab` is able to execute the `script.py` without that error. How can I fix that?

Comment: Without more details on your X setup on a raspberry it will be hard for us to answer. Is the x server running already? Does other x11 applications (like xterm) work with the cronjob?

Comment: I'm a beginner and not really sure if that is what you want to know:
I run `xhost local:root`. The x server should be running, I have a grafical interface/ desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved my problem. Everything was fine, but i was using the `root crontab`. The `root crontab` was not able to find the display, before the display was not mentioned/used by another command. I transferred my `cronjobs` to the "normal" `crontab` and everything works fine. 
Another point is that commands, which need the display (for example Tkinter) do not work if you start them `@reboot`. You have to implement some sleep time (~30 seconds) in your script, so the display has time to become available.

```
import time

time.sleep(30)

...
```